# It's possible to make a string global which is taken from database?

Tags: java, android, string

```
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String email = user.get("email");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtEmail.setText(email);
```

I want to make the string name global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class GlobalUserDetails {
    private static volatile String name = "not set";
    public static void setName(String name) {
        GlobalUserDetails.name = name;
    }
    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This class will allow you to set a VM-wide 'name'.  Naturally, there will only be one winner if you end up trying to set this global value from a bunch of places, so I am not sure if it's what you really mean by "global".  But there it is: a safe way to set a static value.

If you need more then you will need to provide some kind of locking around it but volatile will ensure that you get something consistent.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by 'global' access your string name from other activities then you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store your strings and retrieve them whenever you want.